# MySQL stored procedure cursor for prepared statements

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a two tables:

```
people_en: id, name
people_es: id, name
```

(please, dont bother about normalization. the design is normalized. the tables are much more complex than this 
but this is just a way to simplify my problem).

I then have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(lang char(2))
BEGIN
    set @select = concat('SELECT * FROM ', lang, ' limit 3');
    PREPARE stm FROM @select;
    EXECUTE stm;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;
    SET @cnt = FOUND_ROWS(); 
    SELECT @cnt;
    IF @cnt = 3 THEN
        //Here I need to loop through the rows
    ELSE
        //Do something else
    END IF;
   END$$
```

More or less, the logic in the procedure is:

If the select gives 3 rows, then we have to loop through the rows and do something with the value in each row.
Otherwise somwthing else (not important what, but I put this to make you understand that I need to have
an if statement before looping.

I have seen and read about cursors, but couldnt find much for selects created by concat (does it matter?)
and especially created with a prepared statement.
How can I iterate through the result list and use the values from each row?
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have some bad and good news for you.

First the bad news.

> MySQL manual says a cursor cannot be used for a dynamic statement that
>   is prepared and executed with PREPARE and EXECUTE. The statement for a
>   cursor is checked at cursor creation time, so the statement cannot be
>   dynamic.

So there are no dynamical cursors so far... Here you would need something like this.

But now the good news: there are at least two ways to bypass it - using vw or tbl.

Below I rewrote your code and applied view to make 'dynamical' cursor.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myproc;
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(IN lang VARCHAR(400))

BEGIN

    DECLARE c VARCHAR(400);
    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM vw_myproc;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    SET @select = concat('CREATE VIEW vw_myproc as SELECT * FROM ', lang, ' limit 3');
    PREPARE stm FROM @select;
    EXECUTE stm;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;

    SET @select = concat('SELECT * FROM ', lang, ' limit 3');
    PREPARE stm FROM @select;
    EXECUTE stm;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;

    SET @cnt = FOUND_ROWS(); 
    SELECT @cnt;
    IF @cnt = 3 THEN
          OPEN cur;
          read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO c;
            IF done THEN
              LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;

            #HERE YOU CAN DO STH WITH EACH ROW e.g. UPDATE; INSERT; DELETE etc
            SELECT c;

          END LOOP read_loop;
          CLOSE cur;
          DROP VIEW vw_myproc;
    ELSE
        SET c = '';
    END IF;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

And to test the procedure:

```
CALL myproc('people_en');
```

Comment: For this scenario, I would assume that CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE privilege will be checked at the point of running the stored routine, rather than at the point of creating it. Right?

Answer (score 7):

@clickstefan, you will have problems with two or more users trying to execute your script at the same time. The second user will get error message 'View vw_myproc already exists' for the line:

```
SET @select = concat('CREATE VIEW vw_myproc as SELECT * FROM ', lang, ' limit 3');
```

The solution is temporary table - it exists for the lifetime of current connection only, and users may simultaneously create temporary tables with the same name. So, code may looks like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vw_myproc;
SET @select = concat('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE vw_myproc AS SELECT * FROM ', lang, ' limit 3');
```

Comment: For this scenario, I would assume that CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE privilege will be checked at the point of running the stored routine, rather than at the point of creating it?

Comment: Create view will also works,  we need to create it based on timestamp, and after procedure execution it would be deleted.
In below statement:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vw_myproc;

table will not create but data may be mixed. if multiple users will call at sametime.